# ModuleError: No module named <appname>.url

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to make a django project, but I can't make an app.

```
python3 manage.py startapp app
```

In settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app',
    <All other django.things>
]
```

In urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('app/', include('app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

*Note: These are exerpts*

But I still get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.urls'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are pointing to **'app/urls'** and there is no file called **urls** in your **app** folder, you externally have to create **urls.py** file in your **app** folder.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', view.your_view_name),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `python3 manage.py startapp app` django create [following directory structure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app).

```
app/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    migrations/
        __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Which means `urls.py` file is not included by default, hence [you have to create one.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view)

Comment: So I need to make the urls.py file?

Comment: Yes. You need to create urls.py file

Answer (score 1):

```
python manage.py startapp app

cd app
```

touch `urls.py` //(if you are on mac or linux) or create from your editor. Make sure to add url config in urls.py of the app or it will raise error

in `settings.py` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list add your app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"app.apps.AppConfig"
]
```